# TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. unet model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_test = np.array(y_test)
```

```
def unet():

  # First block Going down
  d1_2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(s,s,3))
  d1_3 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d1_2)

  # Second block Going down
  d2_1 = MaxPooling2D()(d1_3)
  d2_2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d2_1)
  d2_3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d2_2)

  # Third block Going down
  d3_1 = MaxPooling2D()(d2_3)
  d3_2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d3_1)
  d3_3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d3_2)

  # Fourth block Going down
  d4_1 = MaxPooling2D()(d3_3)
  d4_2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d4_1)
  d4_3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d4_2)

  # Fifth block 
  d5_1 = MaxPooling2D()(d4_3)
  d5_2 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d5_1)
  d5_3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d5_2)

  # Fourth block going up, concatenated with Fourth block going down
  up4_0 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d5_3)
  up4_1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([d4_3, up4_0])
  up4_2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up4_1)
  up4_3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up4_2)

  # Third block going up, concatenated with Third block going down
  up3_0 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(up4_3)
  up3_1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([d3_3, up3_0])
  up3_2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up3_1)
  up3_3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up3_2)

  # Second block going up, concatenated with Second block going down
  up2_0 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(up3_3)
  up2_1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([d2_3, up2_0])
  up2_2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up2_1)
  up2_3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up2_2)

  # First block going up, concatenated with First block going down
  up1_0 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(up2_3)
  up1_1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([d1_3, up1_0])
  up1_2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up1_1)
  up1_3 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up1_2)

  # Output
  out = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(up1_3)

  return out
```

some answer to a similar question suggested using **as_numpy_iterator.next()** so I'm passing one batch at a time instead of the whole dataset

```
from keras.layers import Input,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,UpSampling2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
unet = Model(unet(),input_shape = (s,s,3))
unet.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = optimizers.rmsprop_v2.RMSprop())
unet_train = unet.fit(X_train.as_numpy_iterator.next(), y_train.as_numpy_iterator.next(), batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1,validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

still run into the same error
**TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <keras.layers.convolutional.conv2d.Conv2D object**

Comment: what is `s` in your code?

Comment: image size 300 X 300

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue at the beginning of 'unet' function:

```
# First block Going down
d1_2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(s,s,3))
```

Please try instead:

```
# First block Going down
inputs = Input(shape=(s,s,3))
d1_2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
```

For more details please check:
https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

"...To build this model using the functional API, start by creating an input node."

Comment: tried your code and now I've this error **ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 40, 40, 128), (None, 38, 38, 128)]** I tried playing around with strides and padding but it doesn't change much.

Comment: This is probably due to integer division rounding: ((a/2))*2 != a 
One possibility to fix this is to chose input size which is power of 2, say 256. Or you can pad smaller shape with 0 to convert (38, 38, 128) to (40, 40, 128).